# Magento 2 Newsletter fake subscriptions

Tags: magento2, security, newsletter

Easily with any email you can subscribe to Magento 2 newsletter.

The only available control is to send confirmation email to provided address.

If provided email address is not valid Magento confirmation email will bounce back.

**The issue is:**

If you are using email provider like **mandrill** or **sendgrid** they are charging per outgoing email, so you are losing money because of this SPAM newsletter subscribers, any solution?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it's not possible. At most you can try to check if the domain in question have MX record and try to connect to its mail server. Even that won't guarantee it is in working condition though.

You absolutely can't check if a particular e-mail exists on it in some standartized way as there are many approaches to masquerade and aliasing that many server employ. Servers can and will report in SMTP exchange non-existent addresses as valid for many reasons in both VRFY and MAIL/RCPT. The only definite answer you can get is that e-mail is invalid if it is rejected by MAIL/RCPT, but being accepted is not definite proof of it being valid, as it can be rejected down the line of e-mail processing. Abusing MAIL/RCPT without actually sending anything can also lead to you being blocked.

If you want to verify user-supplied e-mail, your best bet is to send confirmation letter there.

You also should review if you really need confirmed working e-mail at all.

Answer (score 1):

I can understand that email providers like mandrill and sendgrid charge for each email you send.

In that case, you may try Google Invisible Recaptcha or you may try [this extension](http://www.ecommercegorilla.com/?ddownload=452) which validates newsletter subscription form for form key every time when a user tries to subscribe.

Reference to above extension is http://www.ecommercegorilla.com/magento-2-fake-subscriber-spam-sign-ups-newsletter-security/.

For invisible recapthca, you may use below extensions and make changes according to your need:

- https://github.com/magespecialist/m2-MSP_ReCaptcha
- https://github.com/scriptua/magento2-invisible-captcha

Comment: MSP is good extension but it is not yet ready for Newsletter

Comment: @AhmadDarwish, have you tried other posted in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable newsletter confirmation, so when they subscribe they get confirmation mail. that way you can easily identify valid email address

for enabling this setting login admin panel and go to

```
Stores  >  Configuration >  Customers  > Newsletter > Need to confirm **(YES)**
```

Comment: Bhai, see once https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/229952/how-to-get-sidemenu-based-on-category-id-in-magento-1-9